# php: alert user to Upload attachment limit and still submit form data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter php app.  User fills out page, submits form for consideration.  The form allows user to attach files with their submission.  There is there is a 5mb limit on the file size that can be uploaded.  When the user exceeds the limit, the form tries to submit, but ends up basically resetting/refreshing itself, so all the fields are blank, user has to reenter data.

How can/should I do two things:
alert user the attachments have exceeded the limit allowed and
submit the form data, excluding the attachments

Comment: Store the inputted fields in a session variable, upon redirect when file upload is too large echo out the stored values as the default values for the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can/should I do two things: alert user the attachments have exceeded the limit allowed and submit the form data, excluding the attachments

That can’t be done in PHP – because when your script runs, the upload has already been done.

There was a `maxlength` for file inputs in HTML 3.2, but that was removed in HTML 4.01. And browser support was bad anyway. (I don’t know if the `maxlength` attribute in HTML5 applies to file upload fields.)

Using the HTML5 File API could be a more promising approach (modern browsers only, of course). Using that it is relatively simple to read the attributes of the selected file(s). So if the size exceeds your maximum value, you could just remove the file upload field from the DOM (or simply set it to `disabled`), if you want to submit only the rest of the form without the file upload field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($_FILES["table_name"]["size"] > 5242880){
      echo 'File are too big';
      // do the rest of the submit
}
```

Comment: The form still tries to submit, but refreshes and blanks out the fields.